# nav bar centered and sticky footer using css

Tags: html, css

I have been searching an answer around without much luck. I checked here regarding the css nav bar but what I found didn't work for me. What I'm looking for might be a tricky but then again some sites display this type of design. 
I'm trying to have a nav bar centered and a sticky footer... well.... sticking at the bottom.
But it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code:

```css
html, body{
height: 100 %;margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
    height: 80px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

nav{
    background-color: darkgray;
    overflow: auto;
}

nav ul{
    margin-top: 10px;
   padding: .7em;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
   background: #444;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
   border-radius: .3em;    

}

nav li{
    float:left;
}

nav a {
    float:left;
   padding: .8em 1.5em;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #555;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
   font: bold 1.1em/1;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #fff #ccc #999 #eee;
   background: #c1c1c1;
   background: linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c1c1c1);      
 }


 nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
   outline: 0;
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
   background: #cc0099;
   background: linear-gradient(#cc0099, #db4db8); 
}

nav a:active {
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
}

nav li:first-child a {
   border-left: 0;
   border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;            
}

nav li:last-child a {
   border-right: 0;
   border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;            
} 


.content{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: darkmagenta;
}

footer{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_nav.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <header>Hi there !</header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="one.html" class="current">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="two.html">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="three.html">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="four.html" >Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="five.html">Five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
        </div>
        <footer>Bye bye</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not too sure what I'm doing wrong but pretty sure I am !

Answer (score 0):

For sticking the footer to the bottom use this:

```
footer{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkblue;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :)

```css
html, body{
height: 100 %;margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
    height: 80px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

nav{
    background-color: darkgray;
    overflow: auto;
}

nav ul{
    margin-top: 10px;
   padding: .7em;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
   background: #444;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
   border-radius: .3em;    

}

nav li{
    float:left;
}

nav a {
    float:left;
   padding: .8em 1.5em;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #555;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
   font: bold 1.1em/1;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #fff #ccc #999 #eee;
   background: #c1c1c1;
   background: linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c1c1c1);      
 }


 nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
   outline: 0;
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
   background: #cc0099;
   background: linear-gradient(#cc0099, #db4db8); 
}

nav a:active {
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
}

nav li:first-child a {
   border-left: 0;
   border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;            
}

nav li:last-child a {
   border-right: 0;
   border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;            
} 


.content{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: darkmagenta;
}

footer{
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
background-color: darkblue;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_nav.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <header>Hi there !</header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="one.html" class="current">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="two.html">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="three.html">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="four.html" >Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="five.html">Five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
        </div>
        <footer>Bye bye</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Demo in JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fmwr15zo/

Comment: What about centering the nav bar ?

Comment: Found a way to center the nav bar by adding this to the `nav` style : `width: fit-content;`

Answer (score 0):

Centering an element with floated elements can be tricky.

Add this to your `nav` style:

```
text-align:center;
```

In your `nav ul` style, change `float: left;` to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

To position `footer` at the bottom of the viewport, use these styles:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a sticky footer, it is possible if you add the `position` attribute followed by the code that states the pixel position at which the division of your HTML code must stay fixed, to your CSS code. In this case, we will use `position: fixed;` followed by `bottom: 0px` to the footer's portion as we want the footer to always stay at the bottom of the page(`bottom: 0px`).
Here is the code:

```css
html, body{
height: 100 %;margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
    height: 80px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

nav{
    background-color: darkgray;
    overflow: auto;
}

nav ul{
    margin-top: 10px;
   padding: .7em;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
   background: #444;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
   border-radius: .3em;    

}

nav li{
    float:left;
}

nav a {
    float:left;
   padding: .8em 1.5em;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #555;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
   font: bold 1.1em/1;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #fff #ccc #999 #eee;
   background: #c1c1c1;
   background: linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c1c1c1);      
 }


 nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
   outline: 0;
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
   background: #cc0099;
   background: linear-gradient(#cc0099, #db4db8); 
}

nav a:active {
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
}

nav li:first-child a {
   border-left: 0;
   border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;            
}

nav li:last-child a {
   border-right: 0;
   border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;            
} 


.content{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: darkmagenta;
}

footer{
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
background-color: darkblue;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_nav.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <header>Hi there !</header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="one.html" class="current">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="two.html">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="three.html">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="four.html" >Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="five.html">Five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
        </div>
        <footer>Bye bye</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

You will find that the content1 and content2 divisions are hidden behind the footer which is always fixed. To avoid this overlapping, add another division of the same size as the footer before the footer.
Hope this helps...

To know more about `position` attribute in CSS, visit https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp